# Can't copy & paste file from comp to usb

Tags: release-loki, settings, pantheon-files, folder, permissions

guys i can't copy & paste file from computer to usb it's says

[image: can't copy file to usb]

i already tried gksudo nautilus, and open as administrator.

thanks

Comment: can you copy in the terminal? "cp myfile.txt usblocation/"

Comment: All the files are locked. You don't have read/write permissions for those folders and files.

Comment: I would check the formatting type using Disks. Some you can't edit from Linux.

Answer (score 1):

`gksudo nautilus` won't work, since elementary OS does not come with Nautilus file manager.

But there's an equivalent to that. Go to **Applications**, right click on **Files**, select **New Window as Administrator**, and enter your password. Then try pasting the file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are trying to paste onto an ISO image or a bootable USB drive formatted for system installation. Can you try using another USB drive and see if you can paste files on it?